# How do you pronounce "trilean"?

Tags: pronunciation

Reading an [answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/446668) on another Stack Exchange site I've discovered the word "trilean", which I had never heard of. I understand its meaning (the context is computer science; boolean logic has two values, "true" and "false", while [trilean logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-valued_logic) has three, namely true, false, and something else), but I don't know how to pronounce it, and it is such a niche word that dictionaries don't report it: a search on [Onelook](https://onelook.com/?w=trilean) doesn't find anything.

1. Is "tri" pronounced /traɪ/ (as in "triangle") or /trɪ/ (as in "trilogy")? [The pronunciation of the prefix "tri" is quite tricky](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/151866/pronunciation-of-the-prefix-tri). If I had to guess I'd go for /trɪ/ as in trilogy, but I'm not sure at all.
2. Also, how do you pronounce "lean" in this case? I expect it to be [as in "boolean"](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/boolean), and not [as in "lean"](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/lean). That is, *lee-uhn* (two syllables), and not *leen* (one syllable).

Comment: Have you tried searching for videos or podcasts? There are a lot of online lectures on logic and computer science.

Comment: There's such a thing as a tristate buffer, and while that's not the same as trilean logic, it's pronounced /traɪ/.

Comment: @StuartF Yeah, but some of those computer science lecturers are inventing their own pronunciation on the fly, aren't they? You'd have to stick to Knuth or somebody nit-picky about pronunciation. Or the person that coined it, since it's likely a fairly new word and might be on the 'tube already.

Comment: @StuartF No, I haven't tried looking for videos, because even if I found one I wouldn't know whether the author is reliable in that regard, as Conrado says. Besides, having an answer here might help others in the future. That said, I've found a Scottish Gaelic pronunciation on [Forvo](https://forvo.com/word/trilean/), but it's a low-quality recording, and again I'm not sure I can trust it. Anyway I'd say it sounds like "tril-yuhn". Which is close to my guess, except that I expected one more syllable.

Comment: [Forvo](https://forvo.com/word/trilean/) has an article titled 'How to pronounce Trilean in Scottish Gaelic', but I suspect that's a different word.

Comment: Since the word is new and based on 'boolean', TRAI tells the listener immediately that you're moving from 2 to 3 states. Are you, aren't you, or is there a zone in between?

Comment: @YosefBaskin In some theories, at least, there is _something_ in between. The most efficient base for storing information has been shown to be _e_, IIRC. Three is the nearest integer to _e_, so CS people have tried to implement base three hardware before. I never heard of any hardware implementations using base _e_.

Comment: With /trɪ/, wouldn't it be a homophone of *trillion*? That said, videos of lectures about it might help.

Comment: Doesn't the context make it obvious the first syllable should be pronounced as 'try…'? Why not go with Alphabet (above)?

Comment: @alphabet — Since [it also goes by *trivalent* and *trinary*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-valued_logic), I'd guess *try* for *trilean*. (The rest of the word’s pronunciation should be a no-brainer, based on *boolean*.)